# Displaying the image for particular time interval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have view controller with UIImageView . In view did load i want to set image on image view for particular time interval.After that image view should be cleared and application should switch to next screen. I have tried following code which is not working:

```
 welcomeImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
sleep(5);
homeScreenController *controller=[[homeScreenController alloc]initWithNibName:@"homeScreenController" bundle:nil];
controller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

In this case it is sleeping before view did load and it is not going to the next screen also. So what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code/..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(goToNextView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}



- (void)goToNextView
{
        homeScreenController *controller=[[homeScreenController alloc]initWithNibName:@"homeScreenController" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to fire a event after a time. I would recommend using performSelector.

```
- (void) hide {
   //For example. 
   [self dismissModalViewController];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad {
   //Setup my image.
   [self performSelector:@selector(hide) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSTimer 
something like this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
.......
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(2.5)
                                              target:self selector:@selector(hideImage) 
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:NO] retain];
....
}

- (void)hideImage
{
 yourImage.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you made a `sleep(5)` inside the Main Thread, that's bad.

try something like

```
[self performSelectorOnBackground:@selector(hide) withObject:nil]
```

and do the thing you want (and the `sleep(5)`) inside the method `-(void)hide` like

```
-(void) hide {
    sleep(5)
    // ...
}
```

Good luck ;)